# Dynamic title value from a rest api not shown in view page source

Tags: angular

I am using angular 6 and trying to set the meta title of different components. I get the value via a REST API request and set the new title using `@angular/platform-browser`, but the titles are not shown when I try to see the source code of the page using "View page source" from the browser. If I check the title from the tab in the browser or via inspect element, the title is updated and correct.

I am trying to fix the title for SEO purposes.

I am using `http.get` to get the value from server and then `title.setTitle()` for changing the title for each component.

Is there a way on how I can fix this so google bots get the correct title?

Thank you

Comment: Angular universal is the Server side rendering way for Angular. Since it is a client side rendered application you cant do that. Checkout more info for SEO on Angular,

Comment: I have been researching for 3 days for this topic and I couldn't find a solution, hence I asked this question. Is there anything I can do to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: depends on your SEO structure if there are multiple pages then you have to go with angular universal, else if  its your home page you can hardcode it. generally seo trackers are smart these days and wait for the initial promises sometimes but un reliable

Comment: I forgot to mention it in the original question, but I am using angular universal. Hardcoding the title is not a solution for me.

Comment: so the title needs to be put in html before writing the file to response and not as an xhr call when app loads